# complex cron job schedule

Tags: cron

I know I can do this if I call a script to check, but I am curious if I can do this with just the cron.

I need to run a job once/year on the first Saturday of July
If that Saturday is July 4th, run it July 5th.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's that *if* that'll get you.

Hmmm. You can do it with a 2 liner:

```
12 12 1,2,3,5,6,7 7 6 ./script.sh
12 12 5 7 0 ./script.sh
```

Line 1: 12:12pm on July 1,2,3,5,6 or 7 only if it's a Saturday

Line 2: 12:12pm on July 5 only if it's a Sunday

Line 1 should cover every case except the 4th, and Line 2 should cover the case where Saturday is the 4th of July.